# zsh new line prompt after each command

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

Can I configure my prompt to show a new line after each command?

To give you an example. In the following screenshot I did run `cat .zshrc`. I want to have a new line between the last output line of the command, `. ~/.zsh_aliases`, and `~ $`.

[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Edit `~/.zshrc` and add the line `precmd() { print "" }`. This will simply print an empty line before the PROMPT is rendered.

Comment: This works, the issue is that it prints a new line before each prompt, even when you start up the shell!  Any way around this??

Comment: @Sethen I know this is now over two years old, but yours is a common question. I've submitted an edit to this answer (which is still a top search result) which addresses this.

Comment: @Ben your edit hasn't been accepted, can you please share your solution.

Comment: A technique to skip the empty line on the first prompt is to wrap `precmd() { print "" }` in `precmd() { … }`. See my answer to that effect with a little explanation.

Answer (score 23):

A variant of some existing solutions, which I find neater than using a magic variable and conditional:

```sh
precmd() {
    precmd() {
        echo
    }
}
```

This puts a blank line before every prompt except the first one: all the first `precmd` invocation does is replace `precmd` with a function that calls `echo`.

Comment: Perfect answer! Any chance an exception could be made for a 'clear' when a newline at top is not required?

Comment: I don’t think so generally. You could alias `clear` to something that would redefine `precmd` in this way, but at that point a magic variable and conditional would probably be cleaner too. You’d probably need to change Ctrl-L behaviour in zle too, somehow, so that it would do this twiddling too. I’m not sure how that’s done.

Answer (score 13):

Another way is by just setting a custom prompt in `~/.zshrc` that includes a newline character. For example:

```
autoload -Uz promptinit
promptinit

PROMPT="
%n@%m:%~ $ "
```

Comment: This is how I ended up doing mine to avoid new lines before each new prompt.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer (authored by @abid-h-mujtaba) always prints a newline, even on the first load of the shell. I submitted an edit that was, for whatever reason, not accepted.

This is what I use in my [personal dotfiles](https://github.com/sudoforge/dotfiles) (see "Window Configuration" in [`zshrc`](https://github.com/sudoforge/dotfiles/blob/master/zshrc)):

```
function precmd() {
    # Print a newline before the prompt, unless it's the
    # first prompt in the process.
    if [ -z "$NEW_LINE_BEFORE_PROMPT" ]; then
        NEW_LINE_BEFORE_PROMPT=1
    elif [ "$NEW_LINE_BEFORE_PROMPT" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "\n"
    fi
}
```

Comment: `echo "\n"` seemed to be printing two blank lines for me, but `echo ""` worked well.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer

Comment: Works for 'reset', 'clear', and between commands, however it doesn't add a newline after CTRL+l.

Answer (score 6):

Following works:

export PS1='
Other text - blah$'

Comment: This answer is helpful for those folks looking to put a newline **within** the prompt string. My interest is to put a newline right before the $ character. This leaves the prompt text one line and the actual $ prompt on a new line.

Answer (score 3):

user926352

> The accepted answer (authored by @abid-h-mujtaba) always prints a newline, even on the first load of the shell. I submitted an edit that was, for whatever reason, not accepted. This is what I use in my personal dotfiles (see "Window Configuration" in zshrc): `function precmd() { # Print a newline before the prompt, unless it's the # first prompt in the process. if [ -z "$NEW_LINE_BEFORE_PROMPT" ]; then NEW_LINE_BEFORE_PROMPT=1 elif [ "$NEW_LINE_BEFORE_PROMPT" -eq 1 ]; then echo "\n" fi }`

I used this answer, but didn't want the new line after a clear. So I added:

```
alias clear="unset NEW_LINE_BEFORE_PROMPT && clear"
```

Just a drop in replacement for clear that also unsets the new line variable.

ATTENTION:
Edited the suggestion above, because I was assigning a function to clear that did the unset and then clear. That made it recursive, so I eventually hit the limit of nested functions. Oops :). You can just do this instead though and it's much simpler and safer. Sorry if someone found this before the edit.

Comment: I did the same but with reset too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old, but I found a way, even if it's not very clean, I just wanted to share it:

```
function precmd {
    if [[ "$NEW_LINE" = true ]] then
        if [[ "${ADD_NEW_LINE}" = true ]] then
            PROMPT=$'\n'"${PROMPT}"
            ADD_NEW_LINE=false
        fi
    else
        PROMPT="${PROMPT}"
        NEW_LINE=true
        ADD_NEW_LINE=true
    fi
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

To print a newline only between the prompts:

```
precmd() $funcstack[1]() echo
```

or if you (want to) use multiple precmd hooks:

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
_precmd_newline_between_prompts() $funcstack[1]() echo
add-zsh-hook precmd _precmd_newline_between_prompts
```

**Explanation:**

With zsh the braces for simple functions are optional, so if it is not clear the first method is equivalent to this one:

```
precmd() {
  $funcstack[1]() {
    echo
  }
}
```

`$funcstack[1]` is special zsh parameter that contains the name of the caller/outer function.

On the first call (before the first prompt) the inner method `$funcstack[1]() echo` won't run yet, but will redefine the outer method, so it will only print a newline on further calls (before additional prompts).

Answer (score 1):

Using zsh with oh-my-zsh, git support and ZSH Powerlevel9k Theme on Ubuntu 18.04, installed like described here:
https://linuxhint.com/install_zsh_shell_ubuntu_1804/

To get the prompt at a new line open:

/usr/share/powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme

Look for the function left_prompt_end()

The function looks like this in orig:

```
# End the left prompt, closes the final segment.
left_prompt_end() {
  if [[ -n $CURRENT_BG ]]; then
    echo -n "%k%F{$CURRENT_BG}$(print_icon 'LEFT_SEGMENT_SEPARATOR')"
  else
    echo -n "%k"
  fi
  echo -n "%f$(print_icon 'LEFT_SEGMENT_END_SEPARATOR')"
  CURRENT_BG=''
}
```

Just add one new-line command. The function should now look like here:

```
# End the left prompt, closes the final segment.
left_prompt_end() {
  if [[ -n $CURRENT_BG ]]; then
    echo -n "%k%F{$CURRENT_BG}$(print_icon 'LEFT_SEGMENT_SEPARATOR')\n"
  else
    echo -n "%k"
  fi
  echo -n "%f$(print_icon 'LEFT_SEGMENT_END_SEPARATOR')"
  CURRENT_BG=''
}
```

Following line was changed from:

```
echo -n "%k%F{$CURRENT_BG}$(print_icon 'LEFT_SEGMENT_SEPARATOR')"
```

To:

```
echo -n "%k%F{$CURRENT_BG}$(print_icon 'LEFT_SEGMENT_SEPARATOR')\n"
```

Prompt on new line : 
[image]

Comment: There is an extra space on the new line. Can you please tell how to remove that extra line?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers above *do work* but with some caveats,
like an annoying newline at startup and newline when terminal gets clear

This solution fixes all of the issues ( Hopefully )

In your .zshrc, add this

```
precmd() {
    precmd() {
        echo
    }
}
```

This will echo a new line after every command *but not at startup*

But we still have another problem - when the terminal gets cleared a newline is echoed. To fix that alias 'clear' to :-

```
alias clear="precmd() {precmd() {echo }} && clear"
```

For me 'Ctrl + L' clears the screen without a newline but if anyone is having issues just add this to your .zshrc

```
bindkey -s '^L' 'clear^M'
```